# Error: Oops. Something didn't work quite right

Tags: botframework, cortana, cortana-skills-kit

[image]

What's going wrong here, I am facing this issue since last 7 days

Comment: What is the Bot Handle and Microsoft App Id for this bot?

Comment: Also, are you using an MSA or AAD account?

Comment: I am signing in via MSA, I can't share the bot handle and app id on a public forum

Comment: Is there anything else I can share which can help?

Comment: @avasal Please email skillsup at microsoft dot com if this is still an issue for you.  This appears to be specific to your bot.